# Apache HttpClient returns entity with empty content

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm trying to get a series of Web pages with the help of Apache HttpClient 4.2 (Java). The problem is: some of HttpEntities in the series has empty content, i.e.:

```
is = new ByteArrayInputStream(EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity))
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
System.out.println(is.available());
```

shows HTTP/1.1 200 OK an 0. For others it shows, e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK and 64344.
If I restart code, another HttpEntities in the series may be empty. I made a recursion of getting Web page in the same program run until getting non zero content - and after some calls I have got it... I run program under Win'XP.

The code itself (without recursion):

```
public InputStream loadURL(String url) throws IOException {
    PoolingClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(connManager);
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            try {
                System.out.println("========================================");
                is = new ByteArrayInputStream(EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));
                System.out.println(is.available());
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println("========================================");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw ex;
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                httpget.abort();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
    return is;
}
```

InputStream is closed in external code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're relying on `available()` to tell you whether the entity is empty or not you are misusing it. It returns the number of bytes that can be read *without blocking.* Check the Javadoc, where you will find a specific warning against using it to predict the total length of the incoming data. That's not what it's for.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Perhaps it was confusing example, because `available()` was only for presentation use. The problem was recognized when I try to parse the received content and there was nothing to parse at all...When I have tried `EntityUtils.toString(entity)` an empty string was returned...